# F# Xamarin Master/Detail Page (For Hamburger Menu)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, f#

I am following [this](https://wolfprogrammer.com/2016/09/02/creating-a-hamburger-menu-in-xamarin-forms/) tutorial about creating a hamburger menu via the master/detail pages.

I created a new Visual Studio 2017 solution using the "Blank Forms App/ Multiplatform -> app" (F#) template

I then ported the C# code to F# like so

```
namespace ChickenSoftware.Hamburger

open Xamarin.Forms

type MenuPage() =
    inherit ContentPage()
    member this.Title = "Menu"

type HomePage() =
    inherit ContentPage()
    let stack = StackLayout(VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center)
    let label = Label(XAlign = TextAlignment.Center, Text = "Welcome to F# Xamarin.Forms!")
    do
        stack.Children.Add(label)

type RootPage() =
    inherit MasterDetailPage()

type App() =
    inherit Application()
    let menuPage = new MenuPage()
    let homePage = new HomePage()
    let rootPage = new RootPage()
    do
        let navigationPage = new NavigationPage(homePage)
        rootPage.Master <- menuPage
        rootPage.Detail <- navigationPage
        base.MainPage <- rootPage
```

When I try and run this, I get this exception on line 26

> Title property must be set on Master page

Googling around a bit, I see that the problem might be that the InitializeComponent() method needs to be called in the .ctor of the MenuPage.  However, I can't seem to locate it like this

```
type MenuPage() =
    inherit ContentPage()
        do
            base.InitializeComponent()
        member this.Title = "Menu"
```

Am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an F# issue. The Title property you are defining is not the ContentPage property Title but a MenuPage property. Cast your MenuPage to a ContentPage and your Title definition will be lost. You need of course:

```
type MenuPage() =
    inherit ContentPage()
    do base.Title <- "Menu"
```

or

```
type MenuPage() =
    inherit ContentPage(Title = "Menu")
```

Comment: one small correction on the 1st sample: 
    do base.Title <- "Menu"